# Multi threading in unity having hiccups

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, unity-game-engine, textures

Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/badjano/e51d61237b9dde1df74536b1bc0bcbcc

I tried removing locks and some other stuff, but this is as optimized as I could do. Is there any way I can make it smoother?

On my end I set it up for 1024 and 16 threads on the inspector, it was the best performance, for the amount of pixels.

I have no idea why its having those pauses.

Comment: Maybe the hiccups are just the garbage collector doing its job?

Comment: thanks @TheodorZoulias, I just found the issue, it was instantiating colors inside the loop

Comment: Does you machine have 32 cores? Otherwise having that many threads (even 16) doesn't seem to make much sense to me ...

Comment: i9 12900kf, but cores and threads are not the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, instantiating Data inside the loop was causing the hiccup, so the problem was actually memory allocation overhead

very smooth now, code updated, mistake in earlier revisions